# data doesn't display correctly in api php

Tags: php, json

I've created a database and its charset is utf8mb4_general_ci.
now I'm trying to build api for this database but I've a problem in displaying Arabic data, this is my config php file:

```
<?php
    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $dbname = "project";
    $conn = new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$dbname);
    if($conn->connect_error) {
        echo "<h1> Failed to connect</h1>";
    }
?>
```

and this is my api php file:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    require_once 'config.php';
    $charset = "UTF-8";
    $conn->set_charset($charset);
    $query = "select * from users";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $output = [];
    while($item = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $output[] = $item;
    }    
    echo json_encode($output,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

this is my result json file

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "username": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f",
        "password": "user1"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "username": "\u062d\u0645\u062f",
        "password": "user2"
    }
]
```

how can I display username with its Arabic characters ?

Comment: what type of error you are facing?

Comment: Arabic data appear like that "\u062d\u0645\u062f"

Comment: Why do you consider this to be a problem? It looks to be correctly displayed

Comment: because I need to read that data in another application if it still like that I'll have another problems with application

Comment: I still don't understand. Are you confused about what JSON is? The 3 Arabic letters look correct to me even when JSON is decoded. I don't see any problem with this.

Comment: Also, `$charset = "UTF-8";
    $conn->set_charset($charset);` is absolutely incorrect. There is no such charset called `UTF-8`. What you are looking for is `utf8mb4`

Comment: I need Arabic data display as ```username : "حمد"``` but it displays ```"\u062d\u0645\u062f"```

Comment: There, I linked you to an answer that explains how JSON encodes characters and how you can opt out of it in PHP

Comment: okay I got it thank you

Comment: @Dharman is right, use `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: Just try `echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`